# How to show more column from database in google maps infowindow?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

Previously I was able to display the infowindow on maps, but it only displayed one value from the database. How do you display more than one database value on the google maps infowindow?
Thanks

This is my GoogleController

```
 public function index()
    {
        $data = Pelabuhan::all();
        $locations = [];
        foreach ($data as $item) {
        $locations[] = [
            $item->nama_pelabuhan,
            $item->latitude,
            $item->longitude,
            $item->title
        ];
        }
        
        return view('sinkopel', [
            'data' => $data,
            'locations' => $locations,
            'title' => 'Home'
        ]);
    }
```

This is my views

```
<div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initMap() {
            const myLatLng = { lat: -8.636176573413225, lng: 117.53647409339307 }; 
            const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                zoom: 9.1,
                center: myLatLng,
            });
  
            var locations = {{ Illuminate\Support\Js::from($locations) }};
  
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  
            var marker, i;
              
            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
                  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    map: map
                  });
                    
                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                      infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }

                  })(marker, i));
  
            }
        }
  
        window.initMap = initMap;
    </script>
  
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key={{ env('GOOGLE_MAP_KEY') }}&callback=initMap" ></script>
```

[This is the results : here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4KoY.png)

Comment: You can directly add HTML in set content it will automatically ocnsider

Comment: Pre defining the `content` parameter and putting html inside it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Maps API Reference for InfoWindow can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindow.setContent

> setContent([content])
>
> Parameters:
>
> content:  string|Element|Text optional The content to be displayed by this InfoWindow.
>
> Return Value:  None

The info window will display whatever you pass to it.

```
infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
```

This line means it will display the contents of `locations[i][0]`.

If you want to display more information, the best way to do that is to format the information with some HTML and pass that to setContent.

```
infowindow.setContent("\
    <h1>My Title</h1>\
    <p>Some text about something</p>\
");
```

Comment: thanks, it worked but now all the data in the database appears, how do you make the data called based on the same id on the markers?

Comment: A conditional statement should work. For example, you can just render the data "if" it had the same ID as the marker clicked.